# Column's value color change based on condition

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I use placeholder control for generating dynamic table. Now I need to make color of one's column value based below on condition, but my if condition is not working. How to do it? Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
 strResults.Append("<tr style='color: black;'>");
 strResults.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"] + "</td>");
 strResults.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Target"] + "</td>");
 strResults.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Actual"] + "</td>");
 if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"] >94% )
    {
 strResults.Append("<td style='color: green;'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"] + "</td>");
  }
 strResults.Append("</tr>");
  }
```

Comment: what will be the value in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"]`? you cannot compare values of different types using `>`

Comment: >94% is the problem..

Comment: What is value of `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"]` ?

Comment: Value like 94.99%, 56.00%..

Comment: @user3510330 : fine then my answer will help you to do this

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do comparison Like what you are doing. Better you parse the Output in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"]` to double and then compare them with `94` not with `94%`; And also parse the double value from the input before comparing it. I suggest to use [`double.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) for comparison

```
double Achievement = 0.0;

if (double.TryParse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"].ToString().Replace("%",""), out Achievement) 
    && Achievement > 94)
{
    strResults.Append("<td style='color: green;'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"] + "</td>");
}            
else
{
    strResults.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Achievement"] + "</td>");
}
strResults.Append("</tr>");
```

Comment: @user3510330 : The `double.TryParse()` will give the converted result/output to the `outParameter`  and returns a boolean value representing the status of the operations, I have added a link in the answer

Comment: @user3510330 : Do you need anymore clarifications regarding this answer? Please don't forget to Mark it as accepted if it solves your issue.